# Hive sql struct mismatch

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table with columns like this:

```
table<mytable>
field<myfield1> type(array<struct>) 
  item<struct>
    cars(string)
    isRed(boolean)
    information(bigint)
```

When I perform the following query

```
select myfield1.isRed
from mytable
where myfield1.isRed = true
```

I get an error:

> Argument type mismatch '': The 1st argument of EQUAL is expected to a primitive type, but list is found

When I query without the where the data looks something like this

```
[true,true,true]
[true,true,true,true,true,true]
[true]
[true, true]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select myfield1[1]
from mytable
where myfield1[1] = true
```

[image]

You can find more info about how to access complex types [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-OperatorsonComplexTypes)